# IP Address to Number differ in Javascript and c#.net

Tags: c#, javascript, ip-address

I need to apply the range validation of the IP Address, for this i used 
http://www.allredroster.com/iptodec.htm

http://javascript.about.com/library/blipconvert.htm

```
    //JAVASCRIPT CODE
    function dot2num(dot) {
        var d = dot.split('.');
        return ((((((+d[0])*256)+(+d[1]))*256)+(+d[2]))*256)+(+d[3]);
    }

    //C# CODE SERVER SIDE
    System.Net.IPAddress ipAdd;
    if (System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out ipAdd))
        return ipAdd.Address;
```

But, in the client side the value returning is quite different then what i am getting on the server side using the IPAddress class.

Comment: They're completely different methods, the IP to Decimal converts an IP address to a decimal and the .Net method [System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx) returns true if its a valid IPAddress.

Comment: It seems that your C# code is accessing and returning an obsolete property of IPAddress called Address.

Comment: @jeremy you missed the`out` parameter.

Comment: @JeremyThompson yeah, i am using the IPAddress.Address property to access the long value of the ipaddress string.

Comment: Perhaps an endian issue.

Comment: @Rich Yes Rich, can you mention the alternative of this obselete property.

Comment: why this is endian issue, i believe its not culture dependent or is it?

Comment: Endian is not culture related. You js uses big endian. Your c# might use little endian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up doing the same in the server side, as the IPAddress.Address is not returning the correct result, I don't know why, but can any one let me know why so?

```
//WORKING CODE NOW

//JAVASCRIPT CODE
function dot2num(dot) {
    var d = dot.split('.');
    return ((((((+d[0])*256)+(+d[1]))*256)+(+d[2]))*256)+(+d[3]);
}

//C# CODE SERVER SIDE
function dot2num(dot)
{
   var ip = IPAddress.Parse(args.Value);
   var ipBytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
   double ipAddress = ipBytes[0] * Math.Pow(256, 3) + ipBytes[1] * Math.Pow(256, 2) + ipBytes[2] * Math.Pow(256, 1) + ipBytes[3];
   return ipAddress;   
}
```

Comment: Just an fyi, you can use left shift to do the same thing you are accomplishing with math.pow there.

Comment: You are return a double, when you should be packing the 4 bytes into a regular System.Int32 (int), in your code. Due to floating point imprecision this could affect the packed bytes.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following function for Javascript?

```
function num2dot(num) {
    var d = num%256;
    for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
        num = Math.floor(num/256);
        d = num%256 + '.' + d;
    }
    return d;
}
```

If you have doubt about which function returns the right value, you can put in the IP address in http://www.ipaddressguide.com/ip and validate it.

Let me know if you need further helps.

Comment: fyi, the code is resolved and js function is already working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would read http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/9d568a3e-9fbf-4acb-92fc-ff629cd8653f on that subject. The System.Net.IPAddress.TryParse can throw off some weird results if the input is not very specific